# Android Brightcove Successful Video Stream

Tags: android, video-streaming, brightcove

Just a question, can anyone present a Android App that streams from brightcove or share a Working Brightcove sourcecode? PLEASE DO NOT COMMENT with what is posted in their forum's or website, already went threw the tech support and their sample code worked perfectly with their Api Token but when I replaced the Token to that of my Clients the Device ran out of Memory (I believed that the loss of memory was due to the large amount of high quality photo's). Any input on Brightcove and Video Streaming?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The player doesn't work at all!

"For these reasons every feature of the HTML5 player might not work for one device or version as it does for another" ( http://support.brightcove.com/en/docs/supported-devices-html5-players ).

That doesn't make any sense because Android is a OS and not a Device. It's like saying " Windows Media Player was built for Windows OS "DESKTOP" but it won't work on a Laptop running Widows OS"  Right that doesn't make any sense either... and neither does the above admission. Thus if the the player doesn't support every device which ones does it support?

Answer (score 0):

YOu want the source in Android bright cove or HTML 5 Code?

Comment: To late ... OOYALA has taken over. Plus I dealt directly with their tech support and they clearly indicated they didn't know what to do so ... I've moved on but if you like I could compare the sdk from February to what they have updated it to.